# Игра крестики-нолики

Tags: java, mvc, javafx

Хочу реализовать на `Java` (в `IDEA`) с использованием `fxml` (`FXML Scene Builder`) и модели `mvc`, вот как выглядит:

Окно входа http://fastpic.ru/view/61/2014/0526/f66b90430be1983cef1ec00c5cabe4b8.jpg.html

Окно игры http://fastpic.ru/view/63/2014/0526/8465a57a90569deb8bd64403c2a43193.jpg.html

Окно настроек создания новой игры http://fastpic.ru/view/63/2014/0526/fb9c94cde0284c0d2b4caaaf59523e0e.jpg.html

Удалось сделать обновление представления по средствам биндинга. Но вот главная проблема - как сделать поле самой игры в зависимости от выбранного количества клеток? Вижу два варианта:

- динамическое создание/удаление множества кнопок (при нажатии на каждую ставится крестик/нолик и кнопка остаётся в нажатом состоянии), но как сделать создание/удаление элементов открытого представления?
- создание таблицы соответствующего размера, при нажатии на каждую ячейку которой ставится соответственно крестик/нолик, но как сделать изменение количества строк и столбцов и отловить в контроллере на какую ячейку нажали? (между прочим ситуация довольно жизненная - в небольшой подработке на другом языке программирования от меня как раз потребовалось в таблице, содержимое которой получалось с SQL-сервера, создание контекстного меню, зависящего от столбца и содержимого строки, на которой было вызвано - и это ещё было самое лёгкое задание)

Так же есть ещё такие проблемы, как сделать, чтобы окно настроек новой игры открывалось поверх открытого окна игры? (второе окно)

И проблема с тем, что при `setResizable(false)` почему-то панель меню не доходит до правого края окна, что вы можете видеть на скриншоте. (а при `setResizable(true)` с ним всё в порядке)

Знаю вопросов задал уже целую кучу и обычно, когда задаёшь на форумах много вопросов в одной теме, то на них на все никто отвечать не будет, но всё же осмелюсь ещё спросить несколько весьма банальных: никак не могу в `FXML Scene Bulder` закрепить объекты в центре или с правого края, а так же вроде можно в процентном соотношении - чтобы я не делал, какой бы Pane не использовал, при изменении размеров окна всё остаётся низменным относительно верхнего левого края.

Comment: Пилите сервер на Java. А на JavaFx можно сделать клиент..

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю интересно ли это кому-нибудь, но может кому-то поможет:

https://github.com/Andrey759/cross-zero

(там можно посмотреть, как были решены различные проблемы, связанные с FXML)

Comment: +1, но имхо Java плохо приспособлена для UI-приложений. Со связкой .NET/WPF проблем, аналогичных вашим, не возникает. (Хотя конечно кроссплатформенность идёт лесом.)